# Cómo resolver este problema básico de js con un array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, objeto

Este es el array:

```
const ovejas = [
  { name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' },
  { name: 'Euge', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo'},
  { name: 'AAAAAaaaaa', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Nnnnnnnn', color: 'rojo'}
]
```

Y me pide que se filtren las ovejas color rojo y que además su nombre contenga las letras n y a.
EL código base que me dan es el siguiente:

```
export default function contarOvejas(ovejas) {
   // aquí tu magia
   return ovejas
   }  
   const ovejasFiltradas = contarOvejas(ovejas)

   console.log(ovejasFiltradas)

// [{ name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' },
//  { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo' }]
```

Mi código hace algo similar pero no exactamente lo que pide, además si retorno de una (como pide el ejercicio) sólo me imprime por consola cuando la llamo a la función, la primer coincidencia y se corta la ejecución. Me pueden ayudar..? Gracias

```js
const ovejas = [
  { name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' },
  { name: 'Euge', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo'},
  { name: 'AAAAAaaaaa', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Nnnnnnnn', color: 'rojo'}
] 
const contarOvejas = (lista) => {
        for (let oveja of ovejas) {
         let reg = new RegExp(/a/i);
         let reg2 = new RegExp(/n/i);
          if (
            oveja.color === 'rojo' &&
            reg.test(oveja.name) &&
            reg2.test(oveja.name)
             ) {
               console.log(oveja);
          }
      }
    };
       contarOvejas(ovejas);
```

Comment: Eh, si te fijas, al correr tu código la salida es exactamente la que te piden. Así pues, no se entiende bien cuál es el problema

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si te refieres a esto:

```js
const ovejas = [
  { name: 'Noa', color: 'azul' },
  { name: 'Euge', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Navidad', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Ki Na Ma', color: 'rojo'},
  { name: 'AAAAAaaaaa', color: 'rojo' },
  { name: 'Nnnnnnnn', color: 'rojo'}
] 

function contarOvejas(ovejas) {
  let output = []
  for (let oveja of ovejas) {
    let reg = new RegExp(/a/i);
    let reg2 = new RegExp(/n/i);
    if (
      oveja.color === 'rojo' &&
      reg.test(oveja.name) &&
      reg2.test(oveja.name)
    ) {
      output.push(oveja)
    }
  }
  return output;
};
const ovejasFiltradas = contarOvejas(ovejas)
console.log(ovejasFiltradas)
```

donde lo que hacemos es crear un array dentro de la función, que he denominado **output**, al cual se van agregando las coincidencias encontradas en el condicional **if** mediante el método [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), y finalmente retornamos ese array mediante **return** al finalizar la función.